# how to sqlite delete multiquery

Tags: sql, sqlite

How to delete sqlite multi query?

DELETE FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.id=2 and table2.id=2

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I iave three table direction, group, students. I deleteing direction parent group and students table row delete

Comment: DELETE from direact, groupp, students WHERE direact.id='value' and groupp.direact_id='value' and students.stady_id='value'

Comment: This query sqlite syntax error "direact, groupp, students"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use like this:

```
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE table1.id=2; DELETE FROM table2 WHERE table2.id=2;
```

execute multiple query at a time.

example:

```
String qry="DELETE FROM table1 WHERE table1.id=2; DELETE FROM table2 WHERE table2.id=2;";
```